# How is water getting onto the garage foundation sill in area near electrical penetration and weep hole?

Tags: electrical, waterproofing, conduit, caulking, weep-hole

[image]

There is a small amount of water that seeps in and shows up on top of the foundation sill on the inside of my garage in this area. It only happens during a hard wind driven rain. Do you think it is more likely to be getting in through the electrical penetration somehow or maybe the weep hole (if not flashed properly during installation)?

The sealant around the electrical area is pretty new and is in good shape. I did not seal the bottom area because It seems like I have read to leave those areas unsealed to let water have a way out. The plate is pretty tight against the brick so it seems like it would be kind of hard for water to make its way up under there , but who knows.

- What do people think about sealing the bottom of the electrical conduit plate vs leaving it unsealed?

Comment: Picture of the outside might help. But still likely to be hard to tell for sure if it's following the electrical into / through the wall, or getting into the wall elsewhere (since you say "hard, wind-driven rain") and getting OUT via the electrical pnetration once it makes its way down that far.

Comment: This is the picture of the outside of the garage.

Comment: Your text mentioned water on the inside, so that was not clear, given it's the only picture and shows water seeping out. Perhaps show the inside as well, then. But it seems likely that the water is coming down from above inside the wall, and using the electrical penetration as an improvised weep rather than getting to/out the exterior weep holes

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. There is no water in this picture. What may look like water is actually a clear sealant. The water shows up on the inside of the garage on top of the foundation sill.

Comment: If the lower concrete is wetted with standing water for a period, you'd be surprised how moisture can weep in right though unsealed concrete